# distinguish between setter called from domain and called from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to do some things in my setter when it's called from Domain classes but not when it's called from hibernate. furthermore i'm using Session Factory so I cant use @PostLoad to triger a flag!

any body has any idea about it?
thanks.

Comment: Actually implementing business logic in setters is a bad design practice. Try to keep them doing only their job - just set values. Why do you need such distinguishing?

Comment: because in my opinion the rule of a setter is to add a little more logic to it! otherwise there is no need for it and i could leave the field public. for instance the value of some other fields depends on this field and after its change i need to change other fields. that fields can be private and no one else even know they exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using annotations and have annotated the fields then Hibernate will use reflection to access the field directly so there should be no issue with implementing custom logic in your setter.

if you are using XML mappings then you can specify Field access:

Section 5.1.11 (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html)

```
The access attribute allows you to control how Hibernate accesses the property at runtime. 
By default, Hibernate will call the property get/set pair. If you specify access="field", 
Hibernate will bypass the get/set pair and access the field directly using reflection. Y
ou can specify your own strategy for property access by naming a class that 
implements the interface org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor.
```

If you want to be sure then something like:

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name){
    if(this.name != null && ! this.name.equals(name){
        //do something
    }

    this.name = name;
}
```